# Présentation systématique et des exceptions. Construction fautive?

Tags: grammaire

Le titre de cette question est éloquent : je tiens la construction  « Présentation systématique et des exceptions » — proposée ici à titre d'exemple — pour fautive, bien qu'elle fasse florès.

En effet au nom « présentation » sont associés d'une part un adjectif épithète et d'autre part un autre nom valant complément déterminatif. La juxtaposition correcte de l'un et de l'autre devrait donc utiliser des constructions différentes aboutissant à ceci :

> Présentation systématique et présentation des exceptions.

Il semblerait que *Le Bon Usage* ne soit pas explicite à ce sujet, bien qu'en son article 215 (6ème éd., p. 155) il traite d'une question présentant une certaine analogie avec les présentes.

Toute précision à ce sujet (pour confirmer ou infirmer mon point de vue) sera bienvenue. S'il vous plaît, pas d'opinion, mais seulement des références à des sources, encore des sources, toujours des sources.

Comment: Référence? Quelle est la source pour cette phrase?

Comment: @Frank — Aucune référence n'est nécessaire ici, car j'ai pris la peine de préciser: "proposée à titre d'exemple". Ouvrez un journal, écoutez la radio ou promenez-vous sur la Toile, et vous trouverez des formes analogues à foison. Au lieu de poser en censeur vétilleux de mes propos, voyez plutôt la réponse circonstanciée de LPH. Sans souffrir particulièrement de la maladie de persécution, j'incline naturellement à croire que je vous dois la notation négative de ma question, dont le caractère infamant retombe sur son auteur au vu de la tenue linguistique de celle-ci et de sa pertinence.

Comment: En fait ta question a obtenu 3 votes négatifs. Je ne sais pas trop pourquoi. Probablement son style.

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t — Le mystère s'ajoute au mystère… 1° Je ne vois qu'un seul vote négatif. Où avez-vous observé qu'il y en a trois — était-ce, comme à la Bourse, une fluctuation passagère? 2° Pourriez-vous qualifier le "style" de ma question? Cela dit, cette question, du plus haut intérêt puisqu'elle porte sur un solécisme courant, a reçu une réponse pertinente (bien que je que lui aie opposé une restriction), en conséquence de quoi je l'ai notée favorablement. Moralité: l'objectivité reste une qualité perfectible pour beaucoup.

Comment: Il n'y a aucune raison pour ces 3 votes négatifs (en effet, il s'agit bien de trois votes), et le fait que l'on ne trouve dans les commentaires absolument rien de substantiel en fait de critique, sauf de vagues insinuations sans fondement, montre qu'il s'agit de trois vote arbitraires motivés par tout autre chose que le soucis de vérité et de propriété.

Comment: @LPH Peut-être l'injonction faite aux autres à laisser leurs opinions au vestiaire tout en laissant libre cours aux siennes dans sa propre question et ses commentaires ? (je n'ai pas downvoté, c'est juste une supposition) :)

Comment: @guillaume31 Je veux bien admettre que l'insistance sur une parfaite rigueur puisse avoir irrité certains lecteurs, mais je  pense qu'il est très exagéré  d'en faire une raison pour un vote négatif; ça ne vaut, au plus, qu'un commentaire.  La seule critique qui a été faite n'est pas justifiée parce qu'il n'est pas nécessaire d'exiger une source pour une construction qui est mise sur la sellette ; on peut exiger un complément relatif au contexte lorsqu'il parait évident que le contexte qui a été fourni n'est pas suffisant pour décider de la validité ou du sens.  (1/2)

Comment: @guillaume31 On peut aussi s'en passer et considérer les divers contextes dans la réponse que l'on va donner. Il y a sur ce site en permanence des questions d'apprenants du français comme seconde langue et même des français qui cherchent des vérifications à des constructions qui sont les leurs et dont ils ne sont pas sûrs. (2/2)

Comment: @guillaume31 — Ici, le terme "injonction" est inapproprié: de ma part, il s'agissait d'un rappel, de mise pour éviter les "moi, je pense que…" stériles de goût très contemporain. Cependant, mon questionnement — quelque peu argumenté, vous l'aurez constaté — visait précisément à valider ou invalider une opinion sur sur la foi de bases grammaticales solides. Une réponse charpentée y a fait suite, levant mes incertitudes à ma grande satisfaction. Il est en revanche regrettable que ce questionnement n'ait pas suscité plus de réactions: les solécismes méritent toute notre attention.

Comment: J'ai le privilège de voir la distribution des votes en cliquant sur le _score_. Mais on peut aussi analyser la [réputation](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/32680/brice-c?tab=reputation), il y a un -2, puis un -4, c'est -2 par vote négatif. Le style, c'est le ton ici, ne pas préjuger de la réponse aiderait, tout comme la suppression du dernier para. Donc la question commencerait avec _au nom..._ et finirait avec _les présentes_ (qui pourrait être plus simplement remplacé par « mon exemple »). À essayer.

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t — Voyez ici même le commentaire de LHP.  Je ne pensais pas être sur un forum consacré aux cas psychologiques mais sur un forum de linguistique. D'ailleurs, si vous êtes attentif, je n'ai pas préjugé de la réponse, mais fait part d'une opinion en demandant à autrui de se prononcer à son sujet.

Answer (score 1):

D'après la définition générale de coordination qui figure dans LBU, 14ème édition, § 260, une telle coordination est impossible.

> **Définition**
> La coordination est la relation, explicite ou implicite, qui unit des éléments de même statut : soit des phrases, soit, à l'intérieur d'une phrase, des termes qui ont la même fonction par rapport au même mot.

Les termes ne sont pas de même nature (adjectif, nom) et la fonction de l'adjectif est « épithète de « présentation »», alors que la fonction de « exception » est « complément de nom ». De prime abord, cette coordination ne serait pas possible, mais cette question n'a pas été tranchée par les grammairiens.

Ce que l'on doit retenir de l'article suivant dans [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjonction_de_coordination_en_fran%C3%A7ais), c'est que les grammairiens ne sont pas toujours d'accord.

> **Coordination d'éléments de natures différentes**
>
> En général, les éléments coordonnés sont de même nature et ont la même fonction. On peut pourtant rencontrer, même dans la langue littéraire, des coordinations d'éléments de natures différentes, mais de fonction identique, ou des cas d'asymétries plus prononcées. Selon l'importance de ces asymétries, certains grammairiens acceptent et d'autres tiennent pour fautives ces constructions.
>
> - « Elle voyait près du général et en costume d'officier anglais, Arthur à qui sans doute elle devait sa prompte délivrance. » Balzac, La Femme de trente ans
> - « Depuis une cinquantaine d'années, et à mesure que l'Encyclopédie et Voltaire éclataient en France, les moines criaient au bon peuple de Milan, qu'apprendre à lire ou quelque chose au monde était une peine fort inutile, » Stendhal, La Chartreuse de Parme
> - « Vous n'êtes plus qu'un homme aujourd'hui, et combien laid ! » Ghelderode, Théâtre
>
> En poussant l'asymétrie encore plus loin, on aboutit à des montages agrammaticaux, que Riegel qualifie de « zeugmes syntaxiques », lorsque les éléments sont de fonctions différentes, et de « zeugmes sémantiques », lorsque les éléments sont sémantiquement incompatibles. Lorsque ces formes sont délibérées, elles constituent des figures de style, visant l'humour ou l'ironie :
>
> - « Plus tard il devint empereur / Alors il prit du ventre et beaucoup de pays » Prévert, Paroles
> - « Cet homme marchait pur loin des sentiers obliques, / Vêtu de probité candide et de lin blanc ; » Victor Hugo, La Légende des siècles, Booz endormi
> - « Alors elle va s' manger une pizza / Au jambon et au centre commercial » Renaud, Mistral gagnant, Le Retour de la Pépette

D'après LBU, 14ème édition, § 265, et selon un raisonnement comparatif, cette coordination n'est pas acceptable.

> **Éléments non susceptibles de coordination**
>
> Certains éléments, quoique apparemment de même fonction, ne sont pas susceptibles de coordination.
>
> Parmi les éléments subordonnés au nom, un élément qui marque
> l'appartenance, la relation, et un élément qui marque la caractérisation :
>
> - *Une grammaire grecque ET systématique.
> - *La boite aux lettres ET de notre maison est peinte en vert.
> - *La maison de mes parents ET où j'ai passé mon enfance
>   a été détruite par les bombes.
>
> Dans l'expression normale, *Une grammaire grecque systématique*, il y a un
> emboîtement, une hiérarchie :
> [Une grammaire grecque] systématique

- Présentation systématique et des exceptions

Dans cette construction il n'est pas question  d'éléments de même nature, ni même d'éléments de même fonction, et encore moins de hiérarchie sous-jacente ; dans « grammaire grecque et systématique », c'est bien de la même grammaire dont il s'agit. Dans « Présentation systématique et des exceptions » il est d'abord question d'une présentation quelconque, qui est systématique, et en plus d'une présentation des exceptions, laquelle est dissociée de l'idée d'avoir été faite de façon systématique. Vu que du point de vue des normes d'assemblage on constate dans cette construction une plus grande incongruité que dans la construction « grammaire grecque et systématique », laquelle est rejeté selon le LBU, il est raisonnable de conclure qu'on se doit de la considérer comme fautive.

Comment: — Bref nous sommes d'accord, hormis sur un point: par principe je récuse  Wikipedia, car le contenu de cette "encyclopédie" n'est validé par aucun comité éditorial et que les auteurs sont anonymes. C'est contraire aux principes heuristiques les plus élémentaires. Vu vos indéniable compétences, la pertinence de mon point de vue ne vous échappera pas. Pour le reste, je vous ai attribué une note favorable et conclus en vous rapportant le mot savoureux d'un de mes confrères jadis qui, décriant les Anglais, les tenait pour capables de dire: "Le lapin est un animal  timide et comestible".